# jQuery onchange - create div

Tags: jquery, html, input, slider

I have a minor thing to do. I have slider (input - range); I need to create jQuery function that will create certain number of divs based on value of slider (in this case in spans from 3 to 25 with default value of 6).

For now I have created slider and div with some css of that div. I just need jQuery function (I presume **onchange**) that will create divs.

**HTML for slider and div:**

```
<div id="square">BLINK</div>

<div id="slajder">
    <form name="forma">
    <input type="range" name="numberEl" id="input" value="6" min="3" max="25" oninput="exiting.value = input.value">
    <output name="numberEl" id="exiting">6</output>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS for div:**

```
#square {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Remove irrelevant tag, improve paragraph structure and headings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, on change. I created a container div to clear out every time. If you don't it will keep appending. Also using clone as there is one div shown by default. If you don't want to show the div by default you can either create the div in javascript only, or make it hidden.

```
$(document).on('change', '#input', function (e) {
var element = $('.square');
$('#Container').html('');
for (i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) { 
element.clone().appendTo("#Container");
}


})
```

Update, better version:

http://jsfiddle.net/b4r25z83/4/

little cleaner:

```
$(document).on('change', '#input', function (e) {
  $('#Container').html('');
  for (i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) { 
             $('.square').first().clone().html((i + 1) + ' BLINK').show().appendTo("#Container");
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b4r25z83/7/